# Express.js blog application — Formatting dates

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I am in the process of learning Node.js/Express.js, and as an experiment I am attempting to build a small blog application.

I render the page, passing the articles:

```
response.render('index.jade', {
    title: 'Blog'
  , locals: {
      articles: articles
  }
});
```

Here's my Jade template for that:

```
h1= title
section
  h1 Articles
  ul
  each article in articles
    li
      a(href='/article/' + article.slug)= article.title
      span  at #{article.created_at}
```

This displays a list of articles with the title and date. However, I need a way of formatting the date into a more readable format. I have discovered libraries that allow you to do this, but my real question is how I should go about integrating this into my template? I can either pass the moment module to the template and format the date inline there, or I can format it in the route and add it onto the `article` object. How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following helpers in my application:

```
date: function (date) {
  return moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
},

fromNow: function(date) { 
  return moment(date).fromNow(); 
}
```

This could depend on your application but I didn't see the need of using different date formats all over my site.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with adding to the template if you want less and clean code. If you want performance, format it in the route itself.

Comment: It seems a bit weird passing it (moment) as a local to the template. Is this completely normal?

Comment: I pass underscore library to template using `app.locals.use` There's not much performance problem. But if there are only a few (2-3) places where you need this, then do the formatting in the router.

Comment: How can I do the formatting inline? Interpolation causes an 'unexpected identifier' error (`#{moment(article.created_at).format('MMM Do \'YY');}`).

Comment: `span= 'at' + moment(article.created_at).format('MMM Do \'YY')`